# Microsoft Message Analyzer disable resolving IP address to their domain names a.k.a turn off AutoIP feature

Tags: networking, wireshark, microsoft-message-analyzer

I'm using Microsoft Message Analyzer to trace network traffic. However, I cannot find an option to disable the resolution of IP addresses to their domain names. This function was called AutoIP (Auto IP Address Resolution).

I'm aware of Wireshark, but what's crucial for me is to display the process name alongside other network information.

If anyone has any idea how this can be turned off, I would be really grateful.